# Insert query help needed

Tags: sql

I have two database say **A** and **B**.

**A** have `a1 table` having column names `userid`,`pin_no` and `B` database have `b1 table` having column names `id`,`badge_no`.

I want to insert data from `a1` to `b1` and `b1` should get updated as and when `a1` updates

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Why do you have to separate databases?

Comment: How do the `[A].[dbo].[a1_table].[userid]` and `[B].[dbo].[b1_table].[id]` ; `[A].[dbo].[a1_table].[pin_no]` and `[B].[dbo].[b1_table].[badge_no]` relate to each other or are you wanting to place a `[pin_no]` column in b1_table?

Comment: i want to place userid in id and pin_no in badge_no  in sql2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the insert with a simple select:

```
insert into DatabaseB.dbo.tableB1 (id, badge_no)
select userid, pin_no from  DatabaseA.dbo.tableA1
```

or inside a trigger:

```
create trigger insertBfromA
on tableA1
after insert
as
begin
    insert into DatabaseB.dbo.tableB1 (id, badge_no)
    select userid, pin_no from  inserted
end
```

same logic you can use for an update

Comment: no problem, just mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `for update` and `for insert` `triggers` to solve your problem.

Check [THIS](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) article for more info!